# Measuring time taken by logstash to output into elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am looking for a way to measure the time logstash takes to output data into elastic search. 
-   There is this elapsed filter 
    https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-elapsed.html, which I think  can be used to measure the time taken to process the message through all the configured filters but not to measure the time taken to output to elastic search
-   I also tried with a batch file with something like

```
echo starttime =  %time%
cd c:\Temp\POC\Mattias\logstash-2.0.0\logstash-2.0.0\bin
logstash agent -f first-pipeline.conf
echo endtime = %time%
```

The problem with this approach is logstash doesn’t stop/exit after finishing a given input file.
Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks and regards,
Priya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elapsed{} filter is for computing the difference between two events (start/stop pairs, etc).

Logstash sets @timestamp to the current time.  If you don't replace it (via the date{} filter), it will represent the time that logstash received the document.

Elasticsearch had a feature called _timestamp that would set a field by that name to the time of the elasticsearch server.  For some reason, they've deprecated that feature in version 2.

As of right now, there is no supported way to get the time that elasticsearch indexed the data, so there is no supported way to determine the lag between logstash and elasticsearch and the processing time required by elasticsearch.

I was hoping that you could add a date field in your mapping and use the null_value to default the value to 'now', but that's not supported.  Hopefully, they'll support that and reinstate this very useful feature.